# How to duplicate Tkinter pop-up

Tags: python, tkinter

So the code initially begins with a pop up asking you if you are ready, then once you select yes, a pop-up appears and if you try and close it, it will duplicate itself. Right now, it cannot duplicate itself.
Sorry if code is bad and riddled with mistakes (I'm just a beginner.) Thanks for helping.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
def a():
    window2 = Tk()
    offset = 300 + 1*10
    window2.geometry('250x50+'+str(offset)+'+'+str(offset))
    window2.title('')
    window2.resizable(False, False)
    la = Label(window2,text = 'ccmeockeoowpeokv.').pack()    
    button = Button(window2, text = 'OK', command = a()).pack() 
def begining():
    window = Tk()
    window.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' %window.winfo_toplevel())
    window.withdraw()
    if messagebox.askyesno("heh", "Ready?.") == True:
        a()
    window.deiconify()
    window.destroy()
    window.quit()
begining()
```

Comment: Do not start more than one root `Tk()`! Use `tk.Toplevel` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **NOT** ever insert `Tk()` if there are the absolute root of application, because it's just gonna make a new App, and **NOT** a new Window

The **only** method is using `Toplevel()`
Here, i explain you a bit

**What is Toplevel()?**
The `Toplevel()` widget is used to create and display the toplevel windows which are directly managed by the window manager

**What is the function of Toplevel()?**
The function of `Toplevel()` is to create a new window, without using `Tk()`. The `Tk()` and `Toplevel()` is almost same, but `Toplevel()` is to create a new window, without even create new application, if you watch some tutorial, the `Tk()` function is used to be creating a new application

**What is the difference between Toplevel() and Tk()?**
`Tk()` is the absolute root of the application, it is the first widget that needs to be instantiated and the GUI will shut down when it is destroyed. `Toplevel()` is a window in the application, closing the window will destroy all children widgets placed on that window but will not shut down the program

I suggest you to read more of the docs, **or** watch some tkinter tutorials on Youtube
Happy coding!